# Moving to position of multi select listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a multi select listbox, which I would like to make searchable. If the searched for value is found in the listbox, I'd like to scroll to that position, but not select it. Is this possible? The code I have so far for searching is :-

```
With lstComm
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Column(6, i) = txtSearch.Value Then

        End If
    Next i
End With
```

...but I'm not sure how to complete the scroll.

Comment: Access doesn't offer a built-in way to scroll list boxes. I can write up a WinAPI answer if you're interested, but it will be rather complicated since Access doesn't offer a built-in way to get the hWnd for a form control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
Dim index As Long
With lstComm
    Dim match As Boolean
    For index = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Column(1, index) = txtSearch.Value Then
            match = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not match Then Exit Sub

    Dim isSelected As Boolean
    isSelected = .Selected(index)

    .Selected(index) = True
    .Selected(index) = isSelected
End With
```

It retrieves the searched item of the listbox.

If no item has been found it exits.

Otherwise it stores the current selection state of that item, selects it to position the listbox, and restores the stored state of the item.

Comment: Selecting and unselecting an item in a listbox does just that, nothing else. It doesn't scroll to the item being selected (for me on Access 2016 using a multi-select list box, at least)

Comment: I've tested that before, of course. It scrolled correctly to the position. Works with listbox controls `Multi Select` set to `Simple` and `Extended`. Microsoft Access 2013.

Comment: On the listbox I'm using (Access 2016 (Office 365), when a row is selected, it's position is being scrolled to.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can say is that this is undocumented behavior and just doesn't work for me (Build 9126). Your mileage may vary, apparently. If you're going to deploy it, I'd do extensive testing beforehand.